# Find what program or device turns display on

Tags: display-settings, nircmd

I'm using program [NirCMD](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to turn display of computer off.

```
"C:\Program Files\nircmd-x64\nircmd.exe" cmdwait 1000 monitor off
```

How can i tell what device or software turns it back on?

Comment: Have you looked in the event viewer?

Comment: @Raystafarian i looked in the event viewer but all i found was an info "An account was successfully logged on." in "Windows Logs > Security" corelated to time of turning display on.